# Відповідник до слова "блокбастер"

Tags: вживання-слів, відповідник

Який може бути відповідник до слова "блокбастер"?

> [Блокбастер](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=152894&page=180) а, ч. Високобюджетний художній фільм.

Хоча це слово вже присутнє в СУМ-20, але воно іншомовне ([англ. blockbuster](https://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Article=3057&action=show)). Чи існує нормативний український відповідник?

Answer (score 1):

Термін [блокбастер](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) має таке значення:

> **Блокба́стер** (англ. Blockbuster, синонім англ. A movie: кіно категорії
>   «А») — термін щодо дуже успішних, високобюджетних вистав і
>   кінофільмів.

Можемо заглянути на [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/blokbaster), де вибраним відповідником є "Кінобомба", однак особисто я не походжуюся із цим, бо і "кіно", і "бомба" є запозиченими словами. Цікавим є варіант "вражастик" (накшталт "[жахастика](https://uamodna.com/articles/zhahastyk/)"), але очевидно, що його ми не знайдемо в жодних словниках, а щоб це слово розповсюдилося потрібно багато часу.

Однак, коли я лише побачив це питання, то одразу ж мені здалося, що "бойовик" є відповідником до "блокбастера". І моїм припущенням знайшлося підтвердження.

Ось [завдання](https://znanija.com/task/8570927) до олімпіади з української мови, і як бачимо, відповідником до "блокбастера" там подається саме "бойовик".У цьому [блозі](http://nrjpkjdf.blogspot.com/2017/01/1.html) також є завдання на підбір відповідників, де "бойовик" підходить до "блокбастера". Більше того, це слово є в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/bojovyk), де воно має таке значення:

> Кінофільм, вистава і т. ін., що користується великим успіхом у
>   глядачів.

Отже, ми можемо зробити висновок, що відповідником до слова "блокбастер" є "**бойовик**".

Comment: блокбастером може бути драма чи комедія

Comment: Я б радше зробив висновок, що значення слова _блокбастер_ ще остаточно не встановилося. «Правильне» значення — високобюджетний успішний (?) фільм, але багато хто асоціює це слово з фільмами-бойовиками (екнш-фільмами), а дехто навіть вважає за прийнятне застосовувати це слово за межами кіноіндустрії (роман-блокбастер, гра-блокбастер).

Comment: Для відповіді брав за основу значення слова "блокбастер" із Вікіпедії та із самого питання, однак згоден, що у багатьох це слово асоціюється із екшн-фільмами і гадаю, що і в цьому випадку слово "бойовик" буде непоганим відповідником.

Comment: В вікіпедії немає нічого про бойовики.

Comment: Я про визначення слова "блокбастер", яке подається в Вікіпедії.